# google_sign_in not working on android. PlatformException after choosing account

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, google-signin

```
E/flutter (11544): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: , null, null)
```

The above error is what I am getting after choosing an account for google sign in on an android device.
I've already tried:

1. Setting up SHA Keys and adding to firebase, then updating google-services.json file
2. I am using a simulator with google play store

It works on IOS but not on android, indicating that some set up is left.